# Spark Twitter API failing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

1. Hi Team

I have been struggling since a week now trying to read popular tags
from Twitter in my Spark Application.

My Environment is as below that is a setup from  our Organization's
Client

Cdh 5.14

Spark 1.6

Scala 2.10

Below is the error i am  getting ,pasting the complete log for
reference .

and i have been trying  the below to solve it but with no avail.

```
    [main] INFO com.unraveldata.agent.ResourceCollector - Unravel Sensor
    4.5.1.1rc0013/1.3.11.3 initializing. 20/01/25 18:12:09 INFO DriverProbe: Spark Live Updates Disabled: true 20/01/25 18:12:09
    INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0 20/01/25
    18:12:10 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ZB609239
    20/01/25 18:12:10 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls
    to: ZB609239 20/01/25 18:12:10 INFO spark.SecurityManager:
    SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users
    with view permissions: Set(ZB609239); users with modify permissions:
    Set(ZB609239) 20/01/25 18:12:10 INFO util.Utils: Successfully
    started service 'sparkDriver' on port 52545. 20/01/25 18:12:10 INFO
    slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started 20/01/25 18:12:10 INFO
    Remoting: Starting remoting 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO Remoting:
    Remoting started; listening on addresses
    :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.9.65.243:50540] 20/01/25
    18:12:11 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses:
    [akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.9.65.243:50540] 20/01/25
    18:12:11 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service
    'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 50540. 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO
    spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO
    spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster 20/01/25 18:12:11
    INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at
    /tmp/blockmgr-2e313029-5057-446c-b3b4-e3fbee2c7afc 20/01/25 18:12:11
    INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.3 MB
    20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering
    OutputCommitCoordinator 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO util.Utils:
    Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 33950. 20/01/25
    18:12:11 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at
    http://10.9.65.243:33950 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO spark.SparkContext:
    Added JAR /home/zb609239/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar at
    spark://10.9.65.243:52545/jars/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar with
    timestamp 1579975931440 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO spark.SparkContext:
    Added JAR /home/zb609239/twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar at
    spark://10.9.65.243:52545/jars/twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar with
    timestamp 1579975931441 20/01/25 18:12:11 INFO spark.SparkContext:
    Added JAR spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar at
    spark://10.9.65.243:52545/jars/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar
    with timestamp 1579975931441 20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO yarn.Client:
    Requesting a new application from cluster with 70 NodeManagers
    20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has
    not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster
    (36864 MB per container) 20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO yarn.Client: Will
    allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
    20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch
    context for our AM 20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up
    the launch environment for our AM container 20/01/25 18:12:12 INFO
    yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container 20/01/25
    18:12:12 INFO yarn.YarnSparkHadoopUtil: getting token for:
    hdfs://nameservice1/user/ZB609239/.sparkStaging/application_1579122798111_703147
    20/01/25 18:12:13 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Created token for ZB609239:
    HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=ZB609239@IUSER.IROOT.ADIDOM.COM,
    renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1579975932976,
    maxDate=1580580732976, sequenceNumber=60369611, masterKeyId=2639 on
    ha-hdfs:nameservice1 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO hive.metastore: Trying
    to connect to metastore with URI
    thrift://tplhc01c001.iuser.iroot.adidom.com:9083 20/01/25 18:12:14
    INFO hive.metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current
    connections: 1 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to
    metastore. 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO metadata.Hive: Registering
    function nvl com.techm.hive.utils.GenericUDFNVL 20/01/25 18:12:14
    INFO metadata.Hive: Registering function row_number
    com.techm.hive.utils.GenericUDFRank 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO
    metadata.Hive: Registering function sysdate
    com.techm.hive.utils.UDFSysDate 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO
    metadata.Hive: Registering function sdate
    com.techm.hive.utils.UDFSysDate 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO
    metadata.Hive: Registering function sysdte
    com.techm.hive.utils.UDFSysDate 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO
    metadata.Hive: Registering function testfunction
    com.techm.hive.utils.UDFSysDate 20/01/25 18:12:14 INFO
    metadata.Hive: Registering function ups org.hue.udf.MyUpper 20/01/25
    18:12:15 INFO hive.metastore: Closed a connection to metastore,
    current connections: 0 20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading
    resource
    file:/tmp/spark-424037da-7567-42d0-8d63-0cd23074b36b/__spark_conf__5410820092210479896.zip
    -> hdfs://nameservice1/user/ZB609239/.sparkStaging/application_1579122798111_703147/__spark_conf__5410820092210479896.zip
    20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to:
    ZB609239 20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing
    modify acls to: ZB609239 20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO
    spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui
    acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ZB609239); users
    with modify permissions: Set(ZB609239) 20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO
    yarn.Client: Submitting application 703147 to ResourceManager
    20/01/25 18:12:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application
    application_1579122798111_703147 20/01/25 18:12:16 INFO yarn.Client:
    Application report for application_1579122798111_703147 (state:
    ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:16 INFO yarn.Client: client token: Token {
    kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service: } diagnostics: N/A
    ApplicationMaster host: N/A ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1 queue:
    root.NONP.HAASAAP0761_10696 start time: 1579975935463 final status:
    UNDEFINED tracking URL:
    http://tplhc01c007.iuser.iroot.adidom.com:8088/proxy/application_1579122798111_703147/
    user: ZB609239 20/01/25 18:12:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application
    report for application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED)
    20/01/25 18:12:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:19
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:20
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:21
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:22
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:23
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:24
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:25
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:26
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:27
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:28
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:29
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:30
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:31
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:32
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:33
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:34
    INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint:
    ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) 20/01/25
    18:12:34 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter.
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter,
    Map(PROXY_HOSTS ->
    tplhc01c007.iuser.iroot.adidom.com,tplhc01c009.iuser.iroot.adidom.com,
    PROXY_URI_BASES ->
    http://tplhc01c007.iuser.iroot.adidom.com:8088/proxy/application_1579122798111_703147,http://tplhc01...),
    /proxy/application_1579122798111_703147 20/01/25 18:12:34 INFO
    ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter:
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter 20/01/25
    18:12:34 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: ACCEPTED) 20/01/25 18:12:35
    INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
    application_1579122798111_703147 (state: RUNNING) 20/01/25 18:12:35
    INFO yarn.Client: client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN,
    service: } diagnostics: N/A ApplicationMaster host: 10.9.65.223
    ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0 queue: root.NONP.HAASAAP0761_10696
    start time: 1579975935463 final status: UNDEFINED tracking URL:
    http://tplhc01c007.iuser.iroot.adidom.com:8088/proxy/application_1579122798111_703147/
    user: ZB609239 20/01/25 18:12:35 INFO
    cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application
    application_1579122798111_703147 has started running. 20/01/25
    18:12:35 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service
    'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port
    60197. 20/01/25 18:12:35 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 60197 20/01/25 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManager:
    external shuffle service port = 7337 20/01/25 18:12:35 INFO
    storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager 20/01/25
    18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block
    manager 10.9.65.243:60197 with 530.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver,
    10.9.65.243, 60197) 20/01/25 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager 20/01/25
    18:12:36 INFO scheduler.EventLoggingListener: Logging events to
    hdfs://nameservice1/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_1579122798111_703147
    20/01/25 18:12:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Registered listener
    com.cloudera.spark.lineage.ClouderaNavigatorListener 20/01/25
    18:12:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Registered listener
    org.apache.spark.UnravelListener 20/01/25 18:12:41 INFO
    cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for
    scheduling beginning after waiting
    maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms) 20/01/25 18:12:59 WARN
    scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 70,
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com, executor 2):
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) at
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    20/01/25 18:13:00 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in
    stage 3.0 (TID 72, tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com, executor 1):
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at
    org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$38.apply(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) at
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    20/01/25 18:13:01 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com: Container marked as failed:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/14/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

    20/01/25 18:13:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in
    stage 5.0 (TID 73, tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com, executor 2):
    ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running
    tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/14/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

    20/01/25 18:13:01 WARN
    cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked
    as failed: container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/14/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000003.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

    20/01/25 18:13:02 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com: Container marked as failed:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/18/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

    20/01/25 18:13:02 WARN
    cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked
    as failed: container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/18/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

    20/01/25 18:13:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in
    stage 5.0 (TID 74, tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com, executor 1):
    ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running
    tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 on host:
    tplhc01d191.iuser.iroot.adidom.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics:
    Exception from container-launch. Container id:
    container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002 Exit code: 50 Stack
    trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507) at
    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Shell output: main : command provided 1 main : run as user is
    ZB609239 main : requested yarn user is ZB609239 Writing to tmp file
    /data/18/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1579122798111_703147/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002/container_e168_1579122798111_703147_01_000002.pid.tmp
    Writing to cgroup task files...


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50
```

My Command at execution is as below

```
spark-submit --queue NONP.HAASXXXX_XXX --conf spark.ui.port=0 --jars
"/home/XXXXX/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar","/home/XXXXX/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar","/home/XXXXX/twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar"
--class com.sparkStreaming.TwitterTags TwitterTagsBT.jar XXXX XXXXXRR RRRREEXX WWEERRDD twittertagfilter --conf
spark.yarn.user.classpath.first=true --conf
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5 --conf
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=8192 --conf
spark.akka.timeout=300 --conf
spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs=300000 --conf
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 --executor-memory 25g
--driver-memory 4g --num-executors 45 --executor-cores 5 --conf spark.executor.extrajavaoptions="-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" --conf
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=truels
```

My Code goes as below.Just to add i have tried with twitter4j
    3.0.6,3.0.3 and 4.0.7 versions as well,for all of them i get the same above error and it doesn't connect.Please advise what would be
    the problem here.

```
package com.sparkStreaming
import org.apache.spark.streaming._ import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._ import
org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window import
org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row import org.apache.spark._ import
org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ import
java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction import scala.io.Codec import
org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils import
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ concat, lit } import
org.apache.spark.sql.types._ import
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf import java.util.Calendar import
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.HadoopConfiguration
import org.apache.log4j._ import
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils import
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._ import twitter4j.Status; import
twitter4j.auth.Authorization import
twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization import
twitter4j.conf.Configuration import
twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

object TwitterTags {

def main(args: Array[String]) { if (args.length < 3) {
System.err.println("Usage: TwitterSentiments <consumer key>
<consumer secret> " + "<access token> <access token secret>
[<filters>]") System.exit(1) } // Set logging level if log4j not
configured (override by adding log4j.properties to classpath) if
(!Logger.getRootLogger.getAllAppenders.hasMoreElements) {
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN) } val Array(consumerKey,
consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4) //val
filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4) // Set the system
properties so that Twitter4j library used by Twitter stream // can
use them to generate OAuth credentials
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret",
accessTokenSecret)

val sparkConf = new
SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterHashTagJoinSentiments").
setJars(Array("/home/zb609239/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar,/home/zb609239/twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar,spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar"))

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN") val stream =
TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters) val stream =
TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,None) val hashtags =
stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split("
").filter(_.startsWith("@")))

val topCounts60 = hashtags.map(hashTag => (hashTag,
1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(86400)) .map { case (topic,
count) => (count, topic) } .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => { val topList = rdd.take(10)
println("\nLatest topics in last 24 hours (%s
total):".format(rdd.count())) topList.foreach { case (count, tag) =>
println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) } })

ssc.start() ssc.awaitTermination()

}

}
```

Comment: I seems like the main error is - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;). Which may mean a classpath issue or incompatible library. can you upgrade to latest Spark and twitter library.

Comment: Please properly format your code and logs. And please try to extract the relevant errors and narrow the code down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Your problem is probably caused by the manual classpath wrangling with custom jars that you're doing. Try to use a proper build tool. Just make sure that the spark libraries that you're combining have compatible spark and scala versions. You shouldn't have to manually specify the versions of every single Twitter lib.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar` was compiled, but you can:

- Spark is compiled with Maven poms. Inspect `pom.xml` for that jar, to determine the dependencies used. For example, https://github.com/cloudera/spark/blob/cdh5-base-1.6.0/external/twitter/pom.xml was compiled with the `4.0.4` version of `twitter4j-stream` artifact.
- If you're using a tool like SBT or Maven in your project, generate a dependency tree (it would look like `sbt "coursierDependencyTree"` or `mvn dependency:tree` but depends on your environment's tools and plugins). Look for the incompatible artifact name ("twitter4j-stream") and see what version it has. Note that it is possible for a transitive dependency to be overridden, in which case the tool's output will tell you.
- Look at the method signatures of the jars (alternatively your own fat jar with all dependencies) using `javap` to confirm they are as expected.